# Saving has_many records in SilverStripe

Tags: silverstripe

I have a `DebatePage` that has_many votes:

```php
static $has_many = array(
    'Votes' => 'Vote'
);
```

and a corresponding `Vote` `DataObject`

```php
static $belongs_to = array(
    'DebatePage' => 'DebatePage'
);
```

When a user clicks "yes", I would like to save a vote for that page.

What is the syntax for that?

I'm looking to do something like this:

```php
$this->dataRecord->Votes()->add($array('motion' => true));
```

How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

similar to what @3dgoo wrote but with a different syntax, taking advantage of `::create()`:

```
$vote = Vote::create(array(
    'Motion' => true
));
$this->Votes()->add( $vote );
```

This implies that on your `DebatePage` the `Vote` relation is called **Votes**. `$belongs_to` still needs to be changed to a `$has_one`-relation.

Comment: Thanks. Thats some nice familiar feeling (from other frameworks) syntax. Is this the new 3.0 orm? is there a documentation page where i could have figured this out for myself?

Comment: I can't be 100% sure it's new to 3.0... just never came across or used it before... The `create` method basically uses the dependency injection (source: http://api.silverstripe.org/3.0/source-class-Object.html#79-107) and here some doc about the `Injector` (http://doc.silverstripe.com/framework/en/3.1/reference/injector). The args for `::create()` are basically then passed to the constructor and for `DataObject` you can pass an array of field values (http://api.silverstripe.org/3.0/source-class-DataObject.html#316-389). Although, all this may not be the easiest thing to find....

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function to create a new Vote in the database:

```
public function SubmitVote() {
    $vote = new Vote();
    $vote->DebatePageID = $this->ID;
    $vote->Motion = true;
    $vote->write();
}
```

Please note, your `Vote` DataObject should have a `$has_one` relationship back to `DebatePage` rather than `$belongs_to`:

```
static $has_one = array(
    'DebatePage' => 'DebatePage'
);
```

Comment: oh ok.  Thanks.  So there isn't a belongs_to in silverstripe?

Comment: there is, but it's for 1-to-1 relations: http://api.silverstripe.org/3.0/source-class-DataObject.html#3434-3445

Comment: this is a good thing to know, I think it's not documented in a good way. I also tried to use the belongs_to relationship for a has_many relations, and I didn't find a document saying that you should use it ONLY for a has_one.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the object to the has_many manually if needed, but it is already done automatically.  If you use $object->ForreignID = $hasOneObject->ID, followed by $form->saveInto($object), it will automatically add the object to the has_many relationship.